# Lower for the inertial degree $f$ in cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

Let $\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}/\mathbb{Q}$ be a galois extension of degree $p-1$ where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p}} $

Let $\mathfrak{b}$ be an ideal above $q$
Where q is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ different from $p$

Then We have
$<q>
=\mathfrak{b}_{1}^{e}......\mathfrak{b}_{r}^{e} $ , by ramification theory we have $rfe=p-1$ where $f $ the is inertial degree and $e$ is the ramification index .

We have

$\mathcal{N}(\mathfrak{b})=|\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{b}|=|\mathbb{F}_{q}|^{f}=q^{f}$

Where $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}/\mathbb{Q}$

By theorem 9.5 in the book of  algebraic number and Fermat last Theorem by Stewart and D.Tall, there is $\alpha \in \mathfrak{b} $ s.t

$$
\mathcal{N}(\alpha) \leq (\frac{ \pi }{2})^{t} \sqrt{\Delta}q^{f}
$$
Thus we get

$\frac{ \log q |\mathcal{N}(\alpha)| \pi^{t}}{2^{t} \sqrt{\Delta}} \leq f $

Where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $t $ is the number of complex embedding in $\mathbb{C} $

I am asking whether the above inequality for $f $ is true  ? and is there a better lower bound for $f$?

Comment: What do you call the ‘interial’ degree?

Comment: For $q$ unramified (ie. $\ne p$) then $e(q)=1,r(q)=(p-1)/f(q)$ and $f(q)=order(q\bmod p)$ is $p$-periodic, we have $f(q)=1$ infinitely often.

Comment: @reuns why $f=order( q$ $ mod p)$?

Comment: Because $O/b$ is the splitting field of $x^p-1\in \Bbb{F}_q[x]$ and $x^p-1$ divides $x^{q^{f(q)}}-x$ iff $q^{f(q)}\equiv 1\bmod p$.

Comment: @reuns is the above inequality true ?